# Some routes are not being generated in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to generate this route:

> /ina-reports/redemptions (get)

To this controller:

```
class TopLevelReports::INA::RedemptionsController < ...
    def index
        ...
    end
end
```

And tried this:

```
scope module: :top_level_reports do
  namespace :ina, path: '/ina-reports', as: :ina_reports do
    resource :redemptions, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

I expected to find `ina_reports_redemptions` when I run `rake routes`, or at least find the word `redemptions` (or `ina` ...) in the whole dump, but routes for that resource are not being generated.

What am I missing?

(Note: controller `TopLevelReports::INA::RedemptionsController` exists if I test the constant in the Rails console; it is located at app/controllers/top_level_reports/ina/redemptions_controller.rb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and ran into the same problem.

There is a typo; `resource` should be `resources`

Try this:

```
scope module: :top_level_reports do
  namespace :ina, path: '/ina-reports', as: :ina_reports do
    resources :redemptions, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Comment: It was not a typo. It was a misunderstanding. Thank you.

Comment: Copy. Other than that you had it perfect